# Is space considered a character?

Tags: windows-7, chat

My OS is Windows 7 and I am building a wireless LAN chat VS wired LAN chat, and I have been wondering if space is considered a character?  And if not why? And if yes why?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, space is a character.  Usually, programmers use "character" to refer to "some individual and indivisible unit of text."  When you're writing out a string or some sequence of text, then you somehow need to mark where in that text the spaces occur.  For this reason, character types usually include some encoding of various types of whitespace - spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.  The main rationale behind this is that it greatly simplifies the implementation of strings.  If your string implementation had to make a distinction between actual text characters and whitespace, it would be much harder to reason about the structure of a string - is it an array?  If so, of what?  If not, then what is it?  Having spaces treated as characters makes the contents of a string uniform and makes it much easier to write programs to manipulate text.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In programming languages, a character is a value from 0 to 255 that includes letters, spaces and even control characters.

Comment: It's been quite a while since characters were restricted to the range 0..255.

Comment: Actually, 0-255 is true of 8-bit encoding schemes, but there are other encodings (for example, the various Unicode encodings) that can use multiple bytes per character (this is how very large character sets like many Asian languages can be represented, since they have far more than 255 characters). 8-bit encoding is actually relatively rare; standard ASCII is 7 bit (0-128), and the rest is usually some flavor of Unicode.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I was indeed thinking of the typical 'char' format since it was unclear exactly what he was asking.  Any of the wide-char formats mean anywhere up to 4 octets at this point and, worse, are variable in length.

Answer (score 1):

Since it has ASCII Value, it is a character.